# Multiple RewriteRules & RewriteConds interfering

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have the following piece of code in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove .php from URL and add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301]

# Rewriting data from URL
RewriteRule ^minecraft/(.*)/$ /minecraft/$1/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^game/(.*)/$ /game/$1/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tool/(.*)/$ /tool/$1/ [NC,L]

# Redirection if file or folder doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ ./router.php?r=/$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

I want to achieve the following:

1. A the user can visit "domain.com/contact/", which will show them the contents of the file "contact.php" in the root directory. (Notice the trailing slash in the URL)
2. The user can visit "domain.com/random-id/" and that request will be routed to "router.php?r=random-id".
3. The user can visit "domain.com/minecraft/random-name/", and that request will be routed to the "minecraft/random-name/"-folder. (With an index.php etc inside)

I cannot seem to figure it out, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301]

# Remove .php from URL and add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Redirection if file or folder doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ router.php?r=/$1 [QSA,L]
```